# Element API: List entries related by tag

Tags: tags, plugin-elementapi

How can I pull out other entries related by tag using the Element API?

In this particular case I'm using the [Similar](https://github.com/aelvan/Similar-Craft) plugin to pull out related entries by tag in the templates. I'm not sure if this would help to provide an easier way or not...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Similar plugin allows access to its `find()` method from PHP and your Element API configuration file.

```
$similarEntriesByTags = craft()->similar->find([
    element => $entry,
    context => $entry->tags,
    criteria => $limitCriteria,
]);
```

This is the equivalent to the Twig example code in the readme.

```
{% set similarEntriesByTags = craft.similar.find({ element: entry, context: entry.tags }) %}
```

If you’re inexperienced in quering for entries or using element criteria in PHP in general have a look a the [Working with Elements](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) article in the Craft documentation.